# Surface parametrization

Tags: calculus

This question may sound naive but still I haven't seen it being discussed in any book. Why do we parametrize surfaces with two variables as opposed to curves? Initially I thought that it is not possible to fill enough points in the space with one variable but there are space filling curves so it is certainly not the reason. Is it because we need to move in two directions?

Answer (score 1):

One-dimensional objects need only one parameter. Two-dimensional objects are best described with 2 parameters. Etc. A space filling curve cannot have a finite arc length or well-defined derivatives everywhere, and is more of theoretical construct than anything useful for calculus. With a two-dimensional surface, one can have smooth, local invertibility of the transformation (a,b) -> S(a,b), except for a few isolated singular points. Integration of a quantity over a surface requires a nice normal, for example, and such a smooth transformation gives it. Oddly enough, it turns out that integration over surfaces may not be well-defined without use of a smoothly varying normal. Approximation by polygonal patches isn't good enough, for example.